# Extract substring from a string column python

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a dataframe like this:

```
name      link
apple    example1.com/dsa/es?id=2812168&width=1200/web/map&resize.html
banana.  example2.com/es?id=28132908&width=1220/web/map_resize.html
orange.  example3.com/es?id=3209908&width=1120/web&map_resize.html
```

Each name's ID is buried in the link, which may have different structure. However, I know that the pattern is 'id=' + 'what I want' + '&'

I wonder, is there a way to extract the `id` from `link` and put it back to the dataframe to get the following:

```
name      link
apple    2812168
banana.  28132908
orange.  3209908
```

I try to use this:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.extract(r'id=\s*([^\.]*)\s*\\&', expand=False)
```

but it returns a column with all `nan`

Also, there may be more than one & in the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Ids are always numbers, so this is somewhat cleaner:

```
df["link"] = df['link'].str.extract(r'id=(\d+)&', expand=False)
print(df)
#     name      link
#0   apple   2812168
#1  banana  28132908
#2  orange   3209908
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes ID is always a number. This works perfectly in this context!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of `positive lookbehind` and `positive lookahead`:

```
df['link'] = df['link'].str.extract('(?<=id\=)(.*?)(?=\&)')


      name      link
0    apple   2812168
1  banana.  28132908
2  orange.   3209908
```

**Details**:

- `(?<=id\=)`: positive lookbehind on `id=`
- `(.*)`: everything
- `(?=\&width)`: positive lookahead on `&width`

Comment: Thank you! I should have mentioned that it is not always `&width` after the id. It doesn't seem to work if I use `df['link'] = df['link'].str.extract('(?<=id\=)(.*)(?=\&)')` Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Yes, by using a so called "non greedy" operator, notice the `.*?`, see edit. Be aware that the accepted solution will not work if the id at one point should contain alphanumeric values.

Comment: Thank you!! This makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 2):

Let tri `split`

```
df['link'].str.split('id=').str[1].str.split('&').str[0]
0     2812168
1    28132908
2     3209908
Name: link, dtype: object
```

Comment: @Tian yw :-) happy coding ~